# A bound on $\sup_{u} \left| \frac{u^{t} A^{-1} u}{u^{t} B^{-1} u} -1 \right| $ in terms of $\sup_{u} \left| \frac{u^{t} A u}{u^{t} B u} -1 \right| $

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, inequality

For positive definite matrices $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ and

$$f = \sup_{u} \left| \frac{\mathbf{u}^{t} \mathbf{A} \mathbf{u}}{\mathbf{u}^{t} \mathbf{B} \mathbf{u}} -1 \right|, $$

I have been trying to establish the stability result

$$ \sup_{u} \left| \frac{\mathbf{u}^{t} \mathbf{A}^{-1} \mathbf{u}}{\mathbf{u}^{t} \mathbf{B}^{-1} \mathbf{u}} -1 \right|  \leq \frac{f^2}{1-f} + 2 \frac{f}{\sqrt{1-f}}$$.

This is an important result as it would imply that convergence of the former quantity to zero would mean convergence of the latter quantity and vice-versa. If someone sees the crucial step in the proof, would they be so kind to share it here?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: I think it is implicit that $f \neq 1$, as the comments have pointed out.

Comment: I am curious (this is not my area of expertise): Is it obvious that $1-f > 0$, so that the RHS is defined?

Comment: Are $A$ and $B$ symmetrical or not ?

Comment: I agree with @Martin that when $f$ is >1 (which can happen...), $\sqrt{1-f}$ isn't defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inequality is true under the assumption that $f<1$. In general, if $P$ is positive definite and $S$ is symmetric, then
\begin{aligned}
\sup_{u\ne0}\left|\frac{u^tSu}{u^tPu}-1\right|
&=\sup_{u\ne0}\left|\frac{(P^{1/2}u)^t(P^{-1/2}SP^{-1/2})(P^{1/2}u)}{(P^{1/2}u)^t(P^{1/2}u)}-1\right|\\
&=\sup_{\|v\|=1}\left|v^t(P^{-1/2}SP^{-1/2})v-1\right|\\
&=\max\left\{\left|\lambda_\max(P^{-1/2}SP^{-1/2})-1\right|,
\,\left|\lambda_\min(P^{-1/2}SP^{-1/2})-1\right|\right\}.
\end{aligned}
It follows that if $a=\lambda_\max(B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2})$ and $b=\lambda_\min(B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2})$, your inequality boils down to
\begin{align}
\max\left\{|a^{-1}-1|,|b^{-1}-1|\right\}
&\le\left(\frac{f}{\sqrt{1-f}}+1\right)^2-1\\
&=\left(\frac{\max\left\{|a-1|,|b-1|\right\}}{\sqrt{1-\max\left\{|a-1|,|b-1|\right\}}}+1\right)^2-1\tag{$\ast$}
\end{align}
whenever $0<b\le a<2$ (we need $a<2$ to make $\sqrt{1-\max\left\{|a-1|,|b-1|\right\}}$ a nonzero real number). We may assume that $|b^{-1}-1|\ne|a^{-1}-1|$, because the case of equality can be obtained as a limiting case. We now consider two possibilities:

1. $|b^{-1}-1|>|a^{-1}-1|$. Then we must have $b\le1$ and $(\ast)$ reduces to
   \begin{align}
   \frac1b-1
   &\le\left(\frac{\max\left\{|a-1|,|b-1|\right\}}{\sqrt{1-\max\left\{|a-1|,|b-1|\right\}}}+1\right)^2-1.
   \end{align}
   Since $x\mapsto\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x}}$ is strictly increasing, it suffices to prove that
   \begin{align}
   &\frac1b-1\le\left(\frac{1-b}{\sqrt{1-(1-b)}}+1\right)^2-1,\\
   \Leftrightarrow\ &\frac1b\le\left(\frac{1-b}{\sqrt{b}}+1\right)^2,\\
   \Leftrightarrow\ &1\le\left(1-b+\sqrt{b}\right)^2,\\
   \end{align}
   which is true because $\sqrt{b}\ge b$.
2. $|a^{-1}-1|>|b^{-1}-1|$. Then we must have $a\ge1$ and $(\ast)$ reduces to
   \begin{align}
   1-\frac1a
   &\le\left(\frac{\max\left\{|a-1|,|b-1|\right\}}{\sqrt{1-\max\left\{|a-1|,|b-1|\right\}}}+1\right)^2-1.
   \end{align}
   Since $x\mapsto\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x}}$ is strictly increasing, it suffices to prove that
   \begin{align}
   &1-\frac1a\le\left(\frac{a-1}{\sqrt{2-a}}+1\right)^2-1,\\
   \Leftrightarrow\ &1+\frac{a-1}{a}\le\left(1+\frac{a-1}{\sqrt{2-a}}\right)^2,
   \end{align}
   which is true because $0<\frac{a-1}{a}\le\frac{a-1}{\sqrt{2-a}}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't know who downvoted.

Comment: Isn't sup$(u^tA^{-1}u)-1)=2-1=1$ ?

Comment: @Empy2 Thanks. I hope the errors are fixed now.

Comment: "The inequality is true" only  under the hypothesis $M=\sup(u^TAu/u^TBU)<2$, that is $f<1$. In fact $M=\max_{\lambda\in U}\lambda$, where $U=\{\lambda;\det(A-\lambda B)=0\}$, with a similar result for $\min(.)$.

Comment: @loupblanc Yes. The condition $f<1$ is incorporated in my answer in the form of $a<2$.

Comment: Yes, I saw that. Yet, it's better to explicitly write the condition from the beginning of the proof (as you did).

Answer (score 2):

Take
$A^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}9070&-7021&1101\\-7021&9337&-6189\\1101&-6189&16622\end{pmatrix}$.

$B^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}9605&4770&-1846\\4770&2604&-918\\-1846&-918&2837\end{pmatrix}$.

The inequality

$f(A^{-1},B^{-1})\leq f^2(A,B)/|1-f(A,B)|+2f(A,B)/\sqrt{|1-f(A,B)|}$

is equivalent to $81.43\leq 13.00$ !!

To find this counter example, I did some random tests, that is, I did what you should have done before writing your post. If you want to do good mathematics, then  you will have to change your method of work.

Comment: For your information, this assertion comes from a highly cited paper of my field. At least, I was polite in my post which is what you should have done if you wanted to get my upvote.

Comment: @JohnK , you have some nerve; it's a sign of good health... i)  About politeness, two days ago, two readers reported that $f$ may be> 1. You answered that we could assume that $f\not= 1$. Then I assumed that that there is no hypothesis on $f$; Consequently, I replaced in the statement $ 1-f $ by $ | 1-f |$; my counter-example satisfies $f>1$ (in general, for random $A,B$, one obtains $f>1$). ii) 
on this website, it is extremely rare that a OP requests the proof of a result published in a paper without indicating that it has read it in a publication; in this sense, you are a phenomenon.

Comment: @JohnK , Of course, we may think that the authors of the paper (give the reference of this paper) are more serious than you and that the required formula is correct; so you have probably omitted the essential hypothesis $ "f <1"$, that is equivalent to $sup(u^TAu /u^TBU)<2$.

Comment: I have not omitted anything but the author may have, which is exactly what I was hoping to find here. Thanks for your input but I don't care whether you approve of my method or not.